# Issue while integrating sonar in Jenkins for Android project

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am getting below command not found error while integration:

```
sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080
/var/folders/cv/k3dczf5d0lsbms1bz_pddnym0000gp/T/jenkins2968219490769913394.sh: line 8:
**sonar:sonar: command not found**
```

I followed these two links for sonar integration in Jenkins.

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins
- https://medium.com/devops-process-and-tools/jenkins-configuration-523f6c3d0896

but not able to implement completely. It is showing command not found error. Below is the attached screenshot of my issue.

[image]

Comment: Clearly `sonar:sonar` is not a valid command. How does your build step looks like?

Comment: What is your build framework? For recent Android projects it should be Gradle. Then you can use the SonarQube scanner for Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

`sonar:sonar` is a maven target, not a command. You should be calling `mvn sonar:sonar`.